# Port range in the argument to PORT command

Tags: c++, curl, ftp, libcurl

Suppose I want to connect to FTP server, then list root directory in active mode (via PORT command). For this I'm going to use cURL library.

Seems, like cURL provides such capability. There's [`CURLOPT_FTPPORT`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FTPPORT.html) option and the official reference says, that *the port may be optionally followed by a '-' to specify a port range.*

```
    if (CURL* curl = ::curl_easy_init())
    {
        guard.reset(curl, ::curl_easy_cleanup);

        ::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://10.0.0.162:21");
        ::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, "localhost:37000-38000");

        CURLcode retval = ::curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (retval != CURLE_OK)
        {
            throw NetworkError(retval, ::curl_easy_strerror(retval));
        }
    }

    ...
```

But here's a problem.

If the first port in the range is not available, `curl_easy_perform` fails with `CURLE_FTP_PORT_FAILED`.

**EDIT**

Output in verbose mode:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: ftp://10.0.0.162:21/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 10.0.0.162...
* Connected to 10.0.0.162 (10.0.0.162) port 21 (#0)
< 220 eugee-server / banner
> USER anonymous
< 331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
> PASS ftp@example.com
< 230-Welcome to ftp.eugeeserver
< 230 User logged in.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
* socket failure: Bad access
* Remembering we are in dir ""
* Connection #0 to host 10.0.0.162 left intact
```

Comment: Show us curl log.

Comment: The log does not show any error associated with ports. Are you sure this is a complete log for a session that failed with `CURLE_FTP_PORT_FAILED`? + Are you sure a result is different when the `37000` is available? Show us a log file for that case too.